# Dato obtenido de la base de datos de Firebase no lo puedo usar fuera de la referencia de la Database SWIFT

Tags: firebase, swift, xcode

Ocurre que necesito usar un valor que obtengo en la Database de Firebase, pero necesito usarlo fuera de la referencia de la base de datos, cuando lo uso dentro no tengo problemas, pero si lo quiero usar fuera de esta me entrega un valor nulo.

Este es el código

```
ref.child("A_Usuarios").child(uidvalue).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            self.username = value?["Usuario"] as? String ?? ""
            self.lat = value?["Latitude"] as? Double ?? 0.0

            self.usuario.text = self.username

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        self.latt.text = String(self.lat)
```

el valor que obtengo en "lat" lo quiero usar fuera de la referencia a la base de datos pero me arroja nulo, sólo cuando lo uso dentro de la referencia a la db me entrega el valor correcto...

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Hola espero esto te ayude.

El problema que estas teniendo me parece que es algo teorico.

No es que no puedas usar tu variable lat, fuera del callback (es a lo que te refieres con dentro de la referencia).

El problema es que ese callback se ejecuta de forma asincrona.

Para explicarte mejor con un ejemplo:

`ref.child("A_Usuarios").child(uidvalue).observeSingleEvent` ... (Se ejecuta en primer lugar)

`self.latt.text = String(self.lat)`  .... (Se ejecuta en segunda lugar)

`{ (snapshot) in // Get user value`  ... (Se ejecuta en tercer lugar).

La solución es simple usa  `self.latt.text = String(self.lat)` dentro del callback.

Si quieres una solución un poco mas elegante puedes agregar un observer a la variable lat, e intentar algo como esto.

```
var lat: Double = 0{
  DidSet{
       self.latt.text = String(self.lat)
  }
}
```

Cada vez que actualices la variable lat, la función DidSet se ejecutara y actualizara tu label automaticamente.

Espero te sirva. Saludos